# Given a series of variables (A, B, C ...), How to form the Sql String Ex "A=? and B=?...." but only taking into account for Non-Empty variables?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a need to form an SQL string for searching data.

I have a very long list of variables such as: `String id, String fName, String city, int custType, ....` and my table in DB have all these columns (ID, Fname, LName, City...)

I want to search data based on the info from provided variables, but only Non-Empty variables should be used in the SQL string.

Ex1 if the variables are like the following:

```
    String id="22";
    String fName="";
    String LName="Tom";
    String city="";
    int custType=0;
```

Then

```
String sql="Select * from Customer ";
String where=" where id=? and LName=?";
sql+=where;
//then call DB
```

Ex2 if the variables are like the following:

```
String id="";
String fName="";
String LName="Tom";
String city="Ny";
String postcode="211";
```

Then

```
String where=" where LName=? and city=? and postcode=?";
```

If there is only 1 variable that is not empty & all others are empty then no need `AND`, ex `String where=" where LName=?"`

I am thinking to put all varibles into a List, but some varibles have int type. I also don't know what is the best logics for forming string like that.

Can you come up any good solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can check for `StringUtils.isBlank()` for String inputs. `int` can't hold `""` so there is no need to check for `""`. Depending upon that you can concatenate Strings to form the final query string. For "And" and other such kind of logic , you can choose to have a flag

Comment: but we have to loop over all the variables ? how

Comment: You have the variables (might be as parameter), check each one. why need loop

Answer (score 0):

You must need one unique key field in your db, so the user must enter that key. Using that you can access the particular user. If u also want to check some other field means you can use "or" instead of "and".

```
String where="where id="?" or fname=? or lname=?...";
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should do it. You should use type int for int values and not String. 
An **int** or **Integer** is an **Object** as well, so you can put it into a **List**. The main logic to build the where filter (`filterSql`) is within method `appendColumnToWhere`.

After that you could use a **PreparedStatement** from `filterSql` and use `setObject(idx,...)` to set the values. The JDBC driver should handle the types of your values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //List of Variables
    String col1 = "Test1";
    int col2 = 5;           //ints are Objects as well.
    String col3 = "";
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";

    //building where part
    StringBuilder whereStatement = new StringBuilder();
    List values = new ArrayList();

    appendColumnToWhere(whereStatement, values, "col1", col1);
    appendColumnToWhere(whereStatement, values, "col2", col2);
    appendColumnToWhere(whereStatement, values, "col3", col3);

    //building select
    String filterSql = sql;
    if (whereStatement.length() > 0) {
        filterSql += " WHERE " + whereStatement.toString();
    }

    //using select
    System.out.println(filterSql);
}

private static void appendColumnToWhere(StringBuilder filter, List values, String colName, Object value) {
    if (value == null
            || (value instanceof String && ((String) value).isEmpty())) {
        //skip empty values
        return;
    }
    if (filter.length() > 0) {
        filter.append(" AND ");
    }
    filter.append(colName).append("=?");
    values.add(value);
}
```